# Ruby Zlib "Symbol Not Found"

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, zlib

### Issue

Zlib cannot be included in any fo my scripts. If it is included, I get this error

```
LoadError: dlsym(0x7f859bc94d90, Init_Zlib): symbol not found - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin11.0/Zlib.bundle
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin11.0/Zlib.bundle
from (irb):1
```

This happens regardless of whether I use built in Ruby or RVM 1.8.7 or 1.9.2

### System

- Macintosh 10.7.3
- Core i7
- 8GB

Comment: That error definitely doesn't appear when you use RVM, because RVM puts the libraries in a completely different location. Please check [this](http://beginrescueend.com/packages/zlib/) page that explains how to install zlib with RVM

Comment: In fact it does, though the paths are different. They reflect the path to the rvm rubies directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please read and follow instructions from:

```
rvm requirements
```

After all the installed packages are installed reinstall your rubies:

```
rvm reinstall 1.8.7,1.9.2
```

If you do not have homberew or macports you can also use RVM to install packages:

```
rvm pkg help
```

Comment: Not an RVM issue as this occurs with the built in ruby as well

Answer (score 0):

`require 'zlib'` rather than `require 'Zlib'`

Comment: I'm no longer having this error and am unable to confirm, but thank you for your answer.